# How Can I Get The Text In Class BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How Can I Get The Text Of This Line:

```
<p class="Type__TypeElement-sc-9snywk-0 dHxvMA ProfileSection__value--1bo-L" data-hj-suppress="true" data-qa="Profile Field: Country">SE</p>
```

I Want To Get The "SE" I tried a lot of things but non of them worked

Comment: Show the code that did not work for you so you may learn what you did wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the following lines:

```
soup.find('p').getText()
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommend a simple library. Here's an example: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<p class="Type__TypeElement-sc-9snywk-0 dHxvMA ProfileSection__value--1bo-L" data-hj-suppress="true" data-qa="Profile Field: Country">SE</p>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
print(doc.p.text)
```